# What is the frequency of a time series for hourly data?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, frequency

I am using R for time-series analysis and predictions, the package 'forecast' to be more precise. I am in a dilemma. I have hourly data that needs a prediction and needs to be analysed. I am using the STLF function, since I set the frequency to 24 (because it's [greater than 13](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast3/)). But, when I make the forecasts for the next 6 hours, with a data set containing 300 points, I get the following forecast:

```
Point          Forecast Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
13.50000       29.60251 21.28421 37.92081 16.88077 42.32425
13.54167       27.84124 18.89136 36.79111 14.15358 41.52889
13.58333       30.89487 21.33420 40.45554 16.27309 45.51665
13.62500       36.04991 25.89498 46.20484 20.51928 51.58053
13.66667       40.40386 29.66798 51.13975 23.98474 56.82298
13.70833       41.13250 29.82644 52.43856 23.84138 58.42362
```

As you can see, the next points are 13.5, 13.54, ... etc. This is like this probably because the data set is containing 300 points, and 300/24 = 12.5, 301/24 = 12.54167, ... etc, and assuming that the first point is considered to be 1 and not 0, so there you have the way the points are provided.

My question is: will I get better results if I adjust the seasonality in a way that will give me forecasts for each hour? I.e. if the next point is 12, then 13, then 14, ... etc, up until 23 and then to start from 0 (24 hours span). If yes, please tell me how to adjust the seasonality to my data? Is there a way for making even more complicated seasonalities? (say, if the data is taken every 5 minutes or so).

Thank you in advance for your answer.